# Search Using Textarea

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

My lecturer assigned me to create a basic ColdFusion system.
I am having problem, to search many values using text area.
How can I code this?

Lets say I have to select many values from a database. How can I submit it, and get all the values?

```
<cfparam name="form.q" default=""> 
<FORM ACTION="#ActionURL#" METHOD="POST"> 
  <textarea name="q" rows="2" cols="30" VALUE="<CFIF IsDefined("q") AND q NEQ "">#form.q#</CFIF>" MAXLENGTH="">#Trim(form.q)#</textarea> 
  <INPUT TYPE="Submit" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Search"> 
</FORM>
```

Lets say I have this values in my Students table.

```
ID               Name             Students_No
-------------------------------------------------
1                A                1234
-------------------------------------------------
2                B                1122
-------------------------------------------------
3                C                3321
-------------------------------------------------
4                D                4413
-------------------------------------------------
5                E                0198
-------------------------------------------------
6                F                6132
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to search student_No 1234, 1122 and 3321. It's a like a group search. This is only an example. The database reach hundreds of data.

Comment: What specific portion are you have a problem with? Submitting the form? Selecting values from a database? Please make your question more specific with the code you're having problems with.

Comment: I am having problem to submit and to select the values. Sorry I didn't specify that earlier.

Comment: You need to post what you've tried so far. Once your form is submitted you can do `<cfdump var="#form#">` to output what is in the form scope

Comment: I only get thru this part.

<cfparam name="form.q" default="">
<FORM ACTION="#ActionURL#" METHOD="POST">
<textarea name="q" rows="2" cols="30" VALUE="<CFIF IsDefined("q") AND q NEQ
"">#form.q#</CFIF>" MAXLENGTH="">#Trim(form.q)#</textarea>
<INPUT TYPE="Submit" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Search">
</FORM>

Comment: and after you click Search where does it go? You're still not explaining you're actual problem

Comment: It'll go the details of information of data inserted in the textarea. I still don't know a way to configure multiple search using textarea yet.

Comment: According to [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) I'd say this portion for `<textarea>` is not necessary: `VALUE="<CFIF IsDefined("q") AND q NEQ "">#form.q#</CFIF>"`

Comment: so, is there any other ways to insert many values(in order to search those values) other than using text area?

Comment: Usually you use simple `<input type="text" />` for that task. User inserts many search criteria separating words with space. Then - on the server side - you parse search phrase and send it to your data repository... say database or search engine.

Comment: i have no problem with standard input type insert @Jacek. the task needed me to search by textarea too.

Comment: @Matt Busche i have update the code.

Comment: Could you give us some examples of those multiple values you want to insert and search? Also, I'd like to know what type of search are your going to perform; some examples would be very helpful.

Comment: @Jacek, i have updated the example of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--- form.cfm: ---**

```
<cfparam name="form.q" default="" />

<form action="search.cfm" method="POST">
<label> Please insert students' ID separated by comma:
<input name="q" value="<cfoutput>#form.q#</cfoutput>" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**--- search.cfm: ---**

```
<cfquery name="searchStudents" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT *
    FROM Students
    WHERE Students_No IN (#form.q#)
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#searchStudents#">
```

This is a very basic example just to show the general idea. In production environment you'd like to use `<cfqueryparam>` and other techniques for controlling the input.

Comment: thanks @Jacek. now I know how to do it. it's just the same with my basic coding. is it possible for me to display the details (if insert many numbers) with NEXT PAGE attribute? just asking for opinion.

Comment: This is what is wrong with StackOverflow. Too many people willingly answer 'I can haz codez' questions like this one.

Comment: @ScottStroz and they answer it while ignoring best practices, cfqueryparam, etc

Comment: @MattBusche Aye, indeed.

Comment: While others apparently have problems with reading. Didn't I say **In production environment you'd like to use <cfqueryparam> and other techniques for controlling the input**?